# What does toSortedMap in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What does the method "toSortedMap"?
According to the documentation we can read:

> Converts this Map to a SortedMap. The resulting SortedMap determines
> the equality and order of keys according to their natural sorting
> order.

But what does `natural sorting order` mean ?
Their example doesn't look sorted.

Comment: absolutely not, I don't know why someone devote it, I told in the documentation it doesn't look sorted

Comment: Do you mean `[b, c, d]` doesn't look sorted or you mean some other example?

Comment: Please add a link to the documentation you're quoting from!

Comment: kotlin official documentation, thanks for help, karma will back to u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature of [toSortedMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-sorted-map.html) is defined as:

```
fun <K : Comparable<K>, V> Map<out K, V>.toSortedMap(): SortedMap<K, V>
```

The sort order thus is defined by the comparison logic defined while implementing `Comparable` by the type `K` resembling the keys.

For numeric and string values, this is most likely the intuitive ascending sort order. For custom types, e.g. `User`, a custom implementation to fulfill the `Comparable` interface must be provided.

Alternatively there is a second signature, which allows to provide a custom `Comparator<in K>` to make use of a custom sort order, if the keys of type `K` don't implement `Comparable<K>` or this implementation does not fullfil the expected ordering.

```kotlin
fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.toSortedMap(
    comparator: Comparator<in K>
): SortedMap<K, V>
```

---

Additional information can be found in the documentation of [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) and [Comparable<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).